# vite does not build tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, vite

I installed tailwind and other tools using `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer vite`

I created tailwind and postcss config files using `npx tailwindcss init -p`

`tailwind.config.js` contains:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`postcss.config.js` contains:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

My CSS file exits in css\tailwind.css and contains:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The CSS file is linked to my HTMl page using `<link href="/css/tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet" >`

When I run vite, my app starts without build errors but tailwind output is not generated.

Comment: Have you actually used any of html classes? And you also need to configure `content` property to tell Tailwind where to find the files with classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to adjust a few settings, feels like you're pretty close.

1. Edit Tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2. Start Vite building script with 'npm run dev' command.

```html
// Open terminal
npm run dev
```

3. (Optional) Copy demo h1 property into your index file and test

```html
<h1 class="text-3xl text-blue-700">Testing</h1>
```

Comment: looks like the OP already has done all that things

Comment: @Nikita no, he did not tell Tailwind where to look for class names to include (see the `content: [ // add your sources here ]` list

Answer (score 10):

This works for me. Once you've done what Tailwindcss says in its docs, in your `vite.config.js` (I tried this on JavaScript file. I am not sure if this works on TypeScript in the same way) import tailwindcss:

```js
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
```

Then add tailwindcss as a PostCSS plugin like this:

```js
css: {
  postcss: {
    plugins: [tailwindcss],
  },
}
```

Once you've done that your `vite.config.js` will look like this:

```js
/*Other imports*/
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    /*something*/
  },
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: working for me, thanks. vite vue-js project.

Comment: Thank a ton. Found this answer after 2 days and it worked like a charm. When using [backend integration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html) feature of vite, it is required to set `css.postcss.plugins` property to `tailwindcss` in vite.config.js file.

Comment: thanks, this saved me! might be useful to have the `import { defineConfig } from 'vite'` at the top of your `vite.config.js` example :-)

Comment: working for me with a vite react project, thanks